# Loop through Laravel model with two models

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I am trying to figure out the best way to approach this. I have two models one Categories and another Inventory. I am wanting to search for a category and each product(inventory) that matches that category model shows in a search result limited to 20 a page. I can get the $category from $cat with no problem. I am just not sure the easiest way to loop through each one with the Inventory model. Does Eloquent have something easy for that? I also don't know how that will affect the paginate

```
public function showCategory($cat) {

    $category = Categories::where('category', '=', $cat)->get();

    $inventory = Inventory::where('sku', '=', $category)->paginate(20);

    $image = Images::where('sku', '=', $category->sku)->first();

    if (is_null($inventory)) {
        return App::abort(404);
    }
    return View::make('inventory.category', array('pageTitle' => $category->category, 'inventory' => $inventory, 'category' => $category, 'image' => $image));
}
```

so if category has lets say soccer as its category I want each product(inventory) that equals that same sku from the Categories model to show as a result

**category**

```
id name sku category
1  Blah  1234  soccer
2  Blah  2222  bball
3  Blah  3333  baseball
4  Blah  4444  soccer
5  Blah  5555  soccer
```

the results I would want to gather would show sort of like this from the inventory table

**inventory**

```
id    name   sku   more_stuff_ineed
1454   Blah  1234  blah
43546  Blah  4444  blah
54567  Blah  5555  blah
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically just make sure your relations are defined properly (I would personally name the Inventory model Product instead, since you are dealing with a Product, not a Inventory.. or maybe InventoryItem..)

So lets say you have a Category model and a Product one; you would define your models like this:

```
class Product extends Eloquent {

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }
}

class Category extends Eloquent {

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Product')
    }

}
```

This assumes that your product has, among the rest of it's data, a column called "category_id", which is how it will be related to a category. In this case, we are assuming  a 'one to many' relationship.. if you decide you want a product to belong to multiple categories, you will need to investigate 'many to many' relationships, and have an additional third table to store the relationships.

Once you have defined your models like this, you can query for products that belong to a category like so:

```
$products = Product::where('category_id', $catId)->paginate(20);
```

Make sure you review the documentation on Eloquent Relationships, shown [here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships), and fully understand the different types of relationships. You need to have a solid handle on it to make sure your tables are defined properly, and your models, and of course that your code uses the correct syntax to query them.

p.s. I noticed you named your models in the plural. Typically the naming convention expected by Eloquent are singular models with PascalCase, and plural (lowercase) table names. So your underlying sql tables for my example would be called "categories" and "products", while the models would be called "Product" and "Category".

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. However, I don't know what I am doing wrong with those relationships but I cannot get them to work. I was able to get it to work with this.         $category = Inventory::join('inventory_categories', 'inventory.sku', '=', 'inventory_categories.sku')
            ->where('inventory_categories.category', '=', $cat)
            ->where('inventory.active', '=', '0')
            ->paginate(20); ....But I would like it to work with the models better.

Comment: A big part of getting Eloquent to work is proper naming. Your files need to be named correctly, your models (and their classes), and the columns in the schema which define the relationship. The naming I outlined in my post should work; just make sure you have the files named the same as the classes. Also, you might not want to use a 'sku' as the column which defines your relationship, you want it to be a column with a reference to the other table's id column, such as the "category_id" I suggested being placed in your products table.

Comment: Frankly I don't think you should have 'sku' in both Product and Category. Unless a Category has it's own sku, it sounds like sku should belong to product and product only. It appears to me like you might need to take a step back and re-examine how to design a relational database in general, and then look at how Eloquent helps when working with one.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will look into it. I am working with tables that I cannot control. They each have their own ID and the sku is their relationship. Nothing i can do about that.

Comment: Ohh, ok I thought you were defining the schema.. if you can't change that to make more sense then you will have to do what you're doing and manually use the query builder to work with your schema. Usually in relational databases you use a column like someothertable_id to refer to another table, and depending on if you have a many-to-many relationship or not you will only need a single id to establish a reference between two tables; Eloquent works based on those assumptions.. you can override relating columns though, by defining them in your 'belongsTo' and 'hasMany' calls; maybe try that.